# Arrow Flow Animation

Tags: workflow

I really need a water flow animation exactly like this.
I'm already using follow path, curve and array modifier but the result not as expectation.

Here's the exact sample I wanted:
[image: pipe flow water]

My result the array is not following the curve path:

[image]

Comment: Your question is not detailed enough. What have you tried and what is wrong with what you tried?

Comment: ok @3pointedit i did add what i've tried

Answer (score 3):

*Array* + *Curve* modifiers should make it work:

- In *Edit* mode make sure that the curve direction is good, if not press <kbd>W</kbd> > *Switch Direction*.
- Put the origin of the curve at its beginning point.
- Put the arrow object at the same point.
- Give your arrow an *Array* modifier with as many *Count* as you want and choose the *Offset* (distance between the arrows).
- Give your arrow a *Curve* modifier, choose the Curve as *Object*, and choose the right *Deformation Axis*.
- Move the arrow along the X or Y axis, depending on the orientation of the curve on the scene.

Comment: ok i did try so i have to move the axis thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes setting the origin point (to be the same) for both objects is very important.